# if element has any of data equal to any of select value

Tags: jquery, html

```js
$('.seltop').change(function(){
$('.title').hide();
var a = $('#selfirst').val();
var b = $('#selsecond').val();
$('.title').each(function(){
// if ($(this).has any of data equal to a or b)) {$(this).show();
});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='title' data-a='gold' data-b='silver' data-c='sky'>lorem</div>
<div class='title' data-a='moon' data-b='sun' data-c='river'>lorem</div>
<div class='title' data-a='octet' data-b='double' data-c='single'>lorem</div>

<select class='seltop' id='selfirst'>
<option>gold</option>
<option>moon</option>
<option>octet</option>
<option>silver</option>
</select>

<select class='seltop' id='selsecond'>
<option>sun</option>
<option>double</option>
<option>sky</option>
<option>river</option>
<option>single</option>
</select>
```

So changing any of `seltop` I need to show only `titles` with some data (`data-a or data-b or data-c`) equal to `a or b`.

Any help?

p.s. for admin - please stop give me this stupid message - `you post is mostly code...`. This is a pure example of a question which is perfectly clear without bla bla stories.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('.seltop').change(function(){
$('.title').hide();
var a = $('#selfirst').val();
var b = $('#selsecond').val();
$('.title').each(function(){
var data_a = $(this).attr("data_a");
var data_b = $(this).attr("data_b");
var data_c = $(this).attr("data_c");
var data_array = [data_a,data_b,data_c];
if($.inArray(a,data_array) || $.inArray(b,data_array)){
$(this).show();
}
 });
 });
```